# Why is the OpenVPN service stuck at 'activating'?

Tags: openvpn

I tried to set up OpenVPN following [this step by step guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04). Now I struggle to start the server using `sudo systemctl start openvpn@server` the output of 
`sudo systemctl status openvpn@server` looks like this:

```
* openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-30 09:16:36 UTC; 2s ago
    Docs: man:openvpn(8)
          https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
          https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
 Process: 417 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 417 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
```

I'm confused about the **activating**.

Answer (score 4):

After two hours of pain I finally managed to get OpenVPN running! This is what I found out.

> openvpn@server.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted

Since I'm running it on a Proxmox LXC container I had to put something into `/etc/pve/lxc/<ID>.conf` on the Proxmox host to create the needed tun device:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/net/tun dev/net/tun none bind,create=file
```

After that change a new error occured:

> ovpn-server[1693]: daemon() failed or unsupported: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)

This was fixed by commenting out in `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`:

```
#LimitNPROC=10
```

---

Helpful resources:

- [Systemd fails to start openvpn in lxd managed 16.04 container](https://askubuntu.com/q/747023/620606)
- [OpenVPN–ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/openvpn-error-cannot-open-tun-tap-dev-dev-net-tun-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2-solved/1614/5)

Answer (score 1):

I also had such an error. Initially I had `server.conf` file with

```
user nobody 
group nobody
```

I changed it to

```
user nobody 
group nogroup
```

and everything worked.

The thing seems to be that the Ubuntu operating system does not have a `group nobody`.

Comment: I just recently ran into this too while fiddling on a Ubuntu machine and came to same conclusion. Thank you!